# Visualforce embedded report - isdtp parameter options

Tags: visualforce, reporting

It's possible to embed a report in a Visualforce page with an iframe:

```
<apex:iframe src="/00OR0000000kA48?isdtp=nv" scrolling="true" height="1588px" width="100%"/>
```

I've found a few different options for the isdtp parameter, but I'm not sure I've got them all.  Here's the ones I know about:

- lt - (leaves off Salesforce formatting, page header and sidebar)
- nv -(leaves off Salesforce page header and sidebar)
- vw - (leaves off Salesforce page header and sidebar)
- mn - (leaves off some Salesforce formatting, page header and sidebar)

Are there any other isdtp options that I've missed?  Also, I'm sure there are features of these options that I have not listed.  What are they?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After I posted this, I found the following link which added to what I found:

http://www.ca-peterson.com/2011/11/magic-isdtp-param.html

I've summarized what I found via this link and elsewhere below.  It should be noted that use of this parameter is not supported by Salesforce.

- vw - leaves off SF page header and sidebar, supports aloha theme,
  allows chatter
- lt - leaves off SF formatting, page header, sidebar, and section
  header
- nv - leaves off SF page header and sidebar (behavior changed Winter
  14 - see link)
- mn - leaves off some SF formatting, page header and sidebar

Comment: Great help here ........... But What If I want to show Header for my Page.
I am facing once situation where -After clicking on one button, my header is disappearing (cause of "nv") - and I dont want it to happen