# navigateToURL not passing the isdtp url parameters from my component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

Below is the simple code

```
({
    gotoURL : function (component) {
        var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
        var urlparam = "isdtp=mn";
        urlEvent.setParams({
          "url": "https://ownsandbox.my.salesforce.com/_ui/chatter/service/ChatterAnswersUi"+'?'+urlparam
        });
        alert(urlEvent);
        urlEvent.fire();
    }
})
```

I am trying to load the chatter answers with isdtp paramters to hide the headers but the url which gets loaded in the browser is without the isdtp param:

**https://ownsandbox.my.salesforce.com/_ui/chatter/service/ChatterAnswersUi**

If I use other param (not isdtp) like below, it does load the page with the params in the url:

```
({
    gotoURL : function (component) {
        var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
        var urlparam = "isdtp1=mn";
        urlEvent.setParams({
          "url": "https://ownsandbox.my.salesforce.com/_ui/chatter/service/ChatterAnswersUi"+'?'+urlparam
        });
        alert(urlEvent);
        urlEvent.fire();
    }
})
```

**https://ownsandbox.my.salesforce.com/_ui/chatter/service/ChatterAnswersUi?isdtp1=mn**

Is this is some security issue or we can have some workaround.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

isdtp is a salesforce classic standard parameter which will give us functionality to work with header and sidebars.
isdtp has no relation with salesforce lightning so you are not able to set it using

```
$A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
```

url event.

isdtp url parameter does not allow to switch to lightning so you are not able to use it.

For more please follow these links:

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000DDWFIA4
[Visualforce embedded report - isdtp parameter options](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32318/visualforce-embedded-report-isdtp-parameter-options)

Comment: Ahh Ok...............