# Dynamic report through custom link- formatting

Tags: reporting, dynamic

I am using Dynamic reports through custom link URL

https://xxx.my.salesforce.com/00Om0000000dka3?pv0={!Contact.Contact_Playhouse__c}&pv1={!Contact.Id}

The report appears as below onclick of customlink . However is it possible to just display report part (circled in red pen)?

[image]

I am not sure if it related to below forum.  can it be used in customlink url and how?
[Visualforce embedded report - isdtp parameter options](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32318/visualforce-embedded-report-isdtp-parameter-options?rq=1)

thanks for your help
athi

Comment: The best you can get is isdtp=mn. 

`https://xxx.my.salesforce.com/00Om0000000dka3?pv0={!Contact.Contact_Playhouse__c}&pv1={!Contact.Id}&isdtp=mn`

Comment: wow .. thanks.. that's what I am looking for.. Although its not read only.. any additional option

Comment: Check the answer I posted, it has other options like vw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve it by adding isdtp=mn parameter to your report url.

> mn=  the header and sidebar are stripped out, but in addition chatter
>   will always be removed as well, and the old salesforce theme
>   (pre-aloha) will be used.

So your url will be:

```
https://xxx.my.salesforce.com/00Om0000000dka3?pv0={!Contact.Contact_Playhouse__c}&pv1={!Contact.Id}&isdtp=mn
```

Src : https://www.ca-peterson.com/2011/12/08/the_magic_isdtp_param/

Comment: I'd forgotten about isdtp.