# Hide sidebar and header iframe url in lightning component

Tags: visualforce, lightning, urlhacking, tag

I have a lightning component in which I load an iframe based on recordid. 
How do I hide the header and sidebar

I used the following but this is not working

```
<iframe src="{!'/098/e?parent_id='+v.recordId15+'?isdtp=mn'}" height="400px" width="1200px" style="border:0px"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I someone bumps into this, hereby my findings (?isdtp=vw):
- ?isdtp=mn does not work on iframe tag
- If needed from a lighting page I chose to open a new tab and then the header and sidebar can be removed.

Example Controller:

```
window.open('/p/attach/NoteAttach?pid='+ recordId15 + '&isdtp=vw&parentname='+Recordinf+'&retURL=/'+ recordId15);
```

Note: in certain circumstances &isdtp=vw or ?isdtp=vw  works

Answer (score 0):

[Visualforce embedded report - isdtp parameter options](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32318/visualforce-embedded-report-isdtp-parameter-options)

I can't find anything about this actually being supported to work with Salesforce so I'm not sure you do have any options if none of those work mentioned in the previous answer.